# Same names of enum and variable

Tags: java

I've got following code (I know its not nice ;) ):

```
public class Clazz1 {

    public int test = 10;

    public enum test {a, s, d, f  }

    void sth() {
        // ...  
        }
}
```

Is there any way to acces this enum? When I type 'test' it always means that int variable. What are rules connected with this situation - why even compiler allows to have enum and int with the same names?

Comment: The joy of having access to source code is that you can change it :-)

Comment: Exactly. The simple answer is 'don't do that'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Clazz1 {

    public int test = 10;

    public enum test {a, s, d, f };

    public static void main() {
        System.out.println("a: " + Clazz1.test.a);
    }
}
```

When this is run

```
$ javac Clazz1.java 
Clazz1.java:8: error: non-static variable test cannot be referenced from a static context
    System.out.println("a: " + Clazz1.test.a);
                                     ^
Clazz1.java:8: error: int cannot be dereferenced
    System.out.println("a: " + Clazz1.test.a);
                                          ^
```

Enumerations are actually special class types and the use of enum keyword causes class to be created.  For instance:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Clazz1 {

    public enum test
    {
    a, b, c, d, e, f;
    };

    public static int test = 10;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Class<?> ec = Clazz1.test.class;
    out.format("Name: %s, constants: %s%n\n", ec.getName(), 
        Arrays.asList(ec.getEnumConstants()));
    }
}
```

You can now use ec and Enum class methods to get the entities.  The thing is that you REALLY don't want to do this.  Because it's equivalent of:

```
class Foo {
       class Bar { }
       int Bar;
}
```

Which will make javac spit unneeded epitaphs.

For more information on Enum reflection classes check java api documentation

Answer (score 3):

<s>Accessing static members of the `test` enum should still work, and the enum constants are static members. Try `Clazz1.test.a`.</s>

Update: no, it doesn't work (see comments), so you'll need to resort to dirty tricks like this:

```
// this works but is awful not compile-time-safe
test a = Clazz1.test.class.getEnumConstants()[0];
```

But there are reasons why the Java [variable naming conventions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) exist: to make situations like this less likely, and Java code more readable:

- Enum names (as other class and interface names) should be in UpperCamelCase
- local variable names and field names should be in lowerCamelCase
- constants (static and final fields) should be in UPPER_UNDERSCORE_CASE.

Comment: I know that this code violes conventions, however I'm wondering what happens there. Clazz1.test.a does not work - void sth() {Clazz1.test ttt = Clazz1.test.a; } gives "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field Clazz1.test". Making enum static does not change anything.

Comment: Actually it doesn't ... there is a real scoping issue. (See below)

Comment: *Making enum static does not change anything* Of course not, enums are always static.

Answer (score 1):

Variable and type names are in different namespaces:

```
String String = "Hello!";
```

Not sure what you mean by "it always means that int variable". *Edit* Ah, I see what you mean;  Sean's answer addresses how to scope the name.

Answer (score 1):

This example is really a bit like driving a car into a wall, and trying to figure out how the engine works by observing which pieces fall part first.

I'd really suggest:

- Distinguish different variables with different names
- Drive your car on the road; don't slam it into walls

IMHO :-)

PS:
The answer is "namespaces".  You can look it up in the Java language spec :-)

Comment: PS: The JLS is here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html.  The answer to your question is here:  http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#33757